# Python claims my venv doesnt have requests module but i have pip3 installed it

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pytorch

Im sure for some of you this will likely be a stupid question but ive spent the last 3 hrs trying to get my first virtual environment working and i still cant seem to get it to work. Ive successfully completed the following.

1. Installed an older version of Python 3.10.10
2. Created a virtual environment from the command line in VSCode.
3. Activated it.
4. Pip3 installed config, and a couple other packages.
5. Tried to run part of a Juypter notebook from a book i bought but its throwing the following error.

[image]

I really dont get what im doing wrong. Requests and Config have both been pip installed. Could someone please shed some light on what stupid thing im missing.

Thanks.

Edit: Ive created a new Venv and although the interpreter in the top right is now showing im still getting an error.

[image]

Comment: Is pip in the same environment as pip3?

Comment: You shouldn't have installed a PyPI package `config` in the first place; the first lines of that notebook would create it for you. Anyway, your notebook is probably not executing in the correct env; by the looks of it (top right corner) it might be using a vanilla Python 3.10 env.

Comment: Honestly im not sure. i used this to create the venv. 
py -3.10 -m venv MyPyTorchMLVenv
i thought Pip3 was to be used for Python 3?

Comment: Please [don't post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: @tripleee sure thing, apologies for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Click on the kernel version in the upper right corner

   [image]
2. Switch to the virtual environment **myTestEnv**.

   [image]

---

**Edit:**

Update the `sklearn` package using the following command

```
pip install --upgrade sklearn
```

Comment: Hi, so i deleted all of my virtual environments and started from scratch and setup a new one. I changed the interpreter as discussed but for some reason its complaining i dont have Sklearn installed even though i just installed it via "pip3 install sklearn".

Ive put a new screenshot in the original post. Thanks for your help so far, you're a legend.

Comment: Try to reinstall with `pip install --upgrade sklearn`. Remember to activate the terminal of the virtual environment.

Comment: This seems to have done the trick pip install -U scikit-learn. If you can add it to your answer ill mark it as complete. Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: Okay, I've done that.